# Load test mongodb with my own query

Tags: mongodb, load-testing

I wrote an aggregation group and count query, and I'm planning to simulate a real-life scenario where I have thousands of users making calls to my system per second (every call will result in one aggregation query) to get a count of their activities.

So I inserted 10 million records (representing user activities) to my database and I used JMeter to simulate the aggregation call but I had the following problems:

- I couldn't change the script per request (I want to provide a user id for each unique call).
- I [discovered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) that JMeter MongoDB Sampler is really slow (it uses db.eval() method which takes the global lock by default)

Since I was not able to do load testing with JMeter for the stated reason, how can I answer the question below:

> How much load my server could handle? in my use case how much 1 server
>   can process aggregation queries (resulted from user activity requests) in 1 second?

Keeping other factors constant (like app code, network, sharding, etc..)

Comment: @AdrianHHH I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would focus first on record generation. If you need to emulate sessions and associate particular requests to particular user IDs, then the easiest approach is to use string manipulation (e.g. put a {USERID} token in the strings, load each line in python/java/bash/etc and replace USERID with your generated IDs for particular session lengths). Basically, I would consider processing the dataset an offline task, which I could stream and manipulate to simulate USERIDs or whatever other sessions. It may take hours to stream the results and manipulate them or you may get away with a quick set of cut/sed/awk scripts or you could load all the records into a separate collection and run a map reduce on them (for example, to aggregate based on jsessionid).

At this point, you will have a text file containing JSON that represents your data set. Create a new collection and import the dataset, slowly waiting.

Now write a script (mongo takes plain old javascript) that executes a series of queries at a particular rate (using async in nodejs or plain old javascript, settimeout and v8). Write a script that ramps up the number of concurrent users or decreases the time between requests. Run that script and monitor your latency and servers, when the latency becomes unacceptable, you have capacity.

Another permutation is to run a similar rampup loadtest against 1M, 2M, 5M, 10M rows, plotting (data set size, requests per second, latency percentiles). This gives a pretty 3D chart for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language to execute your queries.

Check out:

- From JMeter main menu: File -> Templates -> MongoDB Load Test
- [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)